# declaration order and assignment

Tags: javascript

```
function() { var w = new Object(), w.x = 10, y = 11; }
SyntaxError: Expected ';'
```

whereas,

```
function() { var w = new Object(), x = w, y = 11; }
```

produces no error and x does have w. What is wrong with the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot *declare* a variable called `w.x`.

Answer (score 3):

The `var` keyword is used to declare variables.

The only things you can put in the comma-separated list following the `var` keyword are variable declarations.

Therefore, your first syntax is invalid - it's read as *declaring* three variables (`w`, `w.x`, and `y`).
The assignment to `w.x` is a statement (which assigns a value to the `w` property of `x`), not a variable declaration, so you need a semicolon to terminate the `var` statement.

Comment: Thanks SLaks, I was trying to declare a variable inside w which is not correct.